# Data Referesh in Power BI from Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, powerbi

I have data in Azure SQL DB, I used import (not directQuery) while making reports in Power BI Desktop, when i published them on Power BI web, I don't see option to schedule data Referesh for the reports.

I have tried installing on-premises data gateway but it fails to configure.

Comment: Does the connection FQDN includes the word secure database.secure.windows.net.? If that is the case, could you replace it by <database name>.database.windows.net

Comment: no it doesn't contain secure.

Comment: By "don't see" you mean it doesn't exist or is it "grey" (inactive)?